# How to avoid changing colors on all buttons if only one is clicked? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, bootstrap-5, dom-manipulation

```js
var cardContent = `[{
    "taskName": "Test Head",
    "image": "./images/test.jpg",
    "description": "Test description",
    "importance": 0

  },
  {
    "taskName": "Test Head",
    "image": "./images/test.jpg",
    "description": "Test description",
    "importance": 0

  },
  {
    "taskName": "Test Head",
    "image": "./images/test.jpg",
    "description": "Test description",
    "importance": 0

  },
  {
    "taskName": "Test Head",
    "image": "./images/test.jpg",
    "description": "Test description",
    "importance": 0

  },
  {
    "taskName": "Test Head",
    "image": "./images/test.jpg",
    "description": "Test description",
    "importance": 0

  },
  {
    "taskName": "Test Head",
    "image": "./images/test.jpg",
    "description": "Test description",
    "importance": 0

  },
  {
    "taskName": "Test Head",
    "image": "./images/test.jpg",
    "description": "Test description",
    "importance": 0

  },
  {
    "taskName": "Test Head",
    "image": "./images/test.jpg",
    "description": "Test description",
    "importance": 0

  },
  {
    "taskName": "Test Head",
    "image": "./images/test.jpg",
    "description": "Test description",
    "importance": 0

  }
]
`


const journalObj = JSON.parse(cardContent);
var cardContainer = document.getElementById("card-space");
// svgs

const trashSvg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
         <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
       </svg>`;
const checkSvg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
         <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
         <path d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z"/>
       </svg>`;

const printCards = () => {
  cardContainer.innerHTML = "";
  journalObj.forEach((card) => {
    cardContainer.innerHTML += `
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="btn bg-info text-start">task</div>
        </div>
        <img src="${card.image}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title text-center h5">${card.taskName}</div><br>
          <div class="card-text text-center">${card.description}</div>
          <hr>
          <div class="card-text"> Importance: <button type="button" data-sortable=“true" class="btn btn-success prio-btn importance" value="${card.importance}"><span class="priority-count">${card.importance}</span></button></div>
          <div class="card-text fst-italic">Deadline</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer bg-transparent text-end">
          <button type="button" class="bg-danger">${trashSvg} Delete</button>
          <button type="button" class="bg-success">${checkSvg} Done</button>
          </div>
    </div> 
    `;
  });
};
printCards();

const increasePriority = () => {
  // assign querySelector All to variable
  const priorityIncrement = document.querySelectorAll(".prio-btn");
  // loop every instance of ".prio-btn"
  priorityIncrement.forEach((button, i) => {
    // assign to every instance an eventlistener
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // on click increment the calue of importance
      journalObj[i].importance++;
      //assing Selector to variable
      const buttonValue = button.querySelector(".priority-count");
      //write the value into the inner value of the cards button
      buttonValue.innerHTML = journalObj[i].importance;
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // abfrage auf werte
        //assign prio-btn class to singe selector in variable
        const buttonColor = document.querySelector(".prio-btn");
        if (journalObj[i].importance < 2) {
          buttonColor.setAttribute("class", "bg-success");
        } else if (
          journalObj[i].importance > 1 &&
          journalObj[i].importance < 4
        ) {
          buttonColor.setAttribute("class", "bg-warning");
        } else if (
          journalObj[i].importance > 4 &&
          journalObj[i].importance < 6
        ) {
          buttonColor.setAttribute("class", "bg-danger");
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
increasePriority();
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container main-content" id="main-content">
  <div class="deckbox">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- row for title of row -->
      <div class="col text-start my-3  fw-bold fs-3 ">Weekly Tasks</div>
      <!-- not yet implemented= line through -->
      <div class="col text-end my-3 fw-normal">Sort by priority:<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" type="button" class="bi bi-sort-up-alt sort" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path
                            d="M3.5 13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4.707L1.354 5.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l2-1.999.007-.007a.498.498 0 0 1 .7.006l2 2a.5.5 0 1 1-.707.708L3.5 4.707V13.5zm4-9.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-1zm0 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3zm0 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5zM7 12.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h7a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5z" />
                    </svg>
      </div>

      <!-- start of row for cards -->
      <div class="row row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-xl-3 row-cols-xxl-3 g-0" id="card-space">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When a button is clicked, the number inside it should go up.
When certain values are reached, the colour of the button should change.

Currently, the numbers go up in each separate instance of the button, but the colours change on every button when only one is pressed.

Like it is

> Press button 1 (button on first card) 2 times, it goes yellow. Press it a third time, ALL other buttons change their colour to yellow. Pass 4 clicks, buttons 4 to 7 change to red while button 1 to 3 stay yellow, button 8 and 9 stay green. All show the right amount of clicks though

How it should be

> Press a button, over 1 it is yellow, over 4 it is red, the other buttons dont change. The numbers change only in the button that was clicked

I can only use JavaScript, bootstrap-5, CSS and HTML atm.

*edit My title is totally messed up :(*

Comment: Create a code snippet to make it easier for people to help you. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0):

OK
After trying around  and running into weird errors
changing the "single instance" querySelector button to the one for querySelectorAll with an index, AND putting all button class elements back in it worked.

```js
var cardContent = `[{
        "taskName": "Test Head",
        "image": "./images/test.jpg",
        "description": "Test description",
        "importance": 0

      },
      {
        "taskName": "Test Head",
        "image": "./images/test.jpg",
        "description": "Test description",
        "importance": 0

      },
      {
        "taskName": "Test Head",
        "image": "./images/test.jpg",
        "description": "Test description",
        "importance": 0

      },
      {
        "taskName": "Test Head",
        "image": "./images/test.jpg",
        "description": "Test description",
        "importance": 0

      },
      {
        "taskName": "Test Head",
        "image": "./images/test.jpg",
        "description": "Test description",
        "importance": 0

      },
      {
        "taskName": "Test Head",
        "image": "./images/test.jpg",
        "description": "Test description",
        "importance": 0

      },
      {
        "taskName": "Test Head",
        "image": "./images/test.jpg",
        "description": "Test description",
        "importance": 0

      },
      {
        "taskName": "Test Head",
        "image": "./images/test.jpg",
        "description": "Test description",
        "importance": 0

      },
      {
        "taskName": "Test Head",
        "image": "./images/test.jpg",
        "description": "Test description",
        "importance": 0

      }
    ]
    `


const journalObj = JSON.parse(cardContent);
var cardContainer = document.getElementById("card-space");
// svgs

const trashSvg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
             <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
           </svg>`;
const checkSvg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
             <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
             <path d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z"/>
           </svg>`;

const printCards = () => {
  cardContainer.innerHTML = "";
  journalObj.forEach((card) => {
    cardContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="btn bg-info text-start">task</div>
            </div>
            <img src="${card.image}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title text-center h5">${card.taskName}</div><br>
              <div class="card-text text-center">${card.description}</div>
              <hr>
              <div class="card-text"> Importance: <button type="button" data-sortable=“true" class="btn btn-success prio-btn importance" value="${card.importance}"><span class="priority-count">${card.importance}</span></button></div>
              <div class="card-text fst-italic">Deadline</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-transparent text-end">
              <button type="button" class="bg-danger">${trashSvg} Delete</button>
              <button type="button" class="bg-success">${checkSvg} Done</button>
              </div>
        </div> 
        `;
  });
};
printCards();

const increasePriority = () => {
  // assign querySelector All to variable
  const priorityIncrement = document.querySelectorAll(".prio-btn");
  // loop every instance of ".prio-btn"
  priorityIncrement.forEach((button, i) => {
    // assign to every instance an eventlistener
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // on click increment the calue of importance
      journalObj[i].importance++;
      //assing Selector to variable
      const buttonValue = button.querySelector(".priority-count");
      //write the value into the inner value of the cards button
      buttonValue.innerHTML = journalObj[i].importance;
      /*--------------------button colour change-----------------------------------------------------*/
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // checking values, assiging correct colour
        if (journalObj[i].importance < 2) {
          priorityIncrement[i].setAttribute(
            "class",
            "btn btn-success prio-btn importance bg-success"
          );
        } else if (
          journalObj[i].importance > 1 &&
          journalObj[i].importance < 4
        ) {
          priorityIncrement[i].setAttribute(
            "class",
            "btn btn-warning prio-btn importance bg-warning"
          );
        } else if (
          journalObj[i].importance > 4 &&
          journalObj[i].importance < 6
        ) {
          priorityIncrement[i].setAttribute(
            "class",
            "btn btn-danger prio-btn importance bg-danger"
          );
        }
      });
      /* -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    });
  });
};
increasePriority();
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container main-content" id="main-content">
  <div class="deckbox">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- row for title of row -->
      <div class="col text-start my-3  fw-bold fs-3 ">Weekly Tasks</div>
      <!-- not yet implemented= line through -->
      <div class="col text-end my-3 fw-normal">Sort by priority:<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" type="button" class="bi bi-sort-up-alt sort" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.5 13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4.707L1.354 5.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l2-1.999.007-.007a.498.498 0 0 1 .7.006l2 2a.5.5 0 1 1-.707.708L3.5 4.707V13.5zm4-9.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-1zm0 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3zm0 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5zM7 12.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h7a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5z" />
                        </svg>
      </div>

      <!-- start of row for cards -->
      <div class="row row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-xl-3 row-cols-xxl-3 g-0" id="card-space">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```